# Average stats monk

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, monk, skills

I am creating a Goliath Monk and I have rolled for my stats and with the STR and CON bonuses Ill have all 13's and one 14. Should I abandon trying to make this monk and just go with something that will be better suited for the totally average stats? Also what would be good for average stats? My rolls were 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14.